# How to include where condition of included relation collections fields in base level

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have two tables alerts and alertTypes. The alert belongs to an alert type which is stored as the object id in alerts table. There is a list of alerts which shows alert basic details and alert type name fetching from alertTypes collection. There is a search filter by which user can enter keywords which will search the fields: alertTitle or alertDescription or alertTypeName matches. But the problem is alertTypeName is in another table which we are fetch using include. How can I write a query which searches the entered keyword likes: alertTitle or alertDescription or alertTypeName.

```
  if (typeof keyword !== "undefined") {
var keywordFilter = new RegExp(".*" + keyword + ".*", 'i');
whereFilter =   {"and": 
                    [
                        {status: {"neq": -1}}, 
                        {createdBy: currentUserId},
                        {"or":
                            [
                                {title: { like: keywordFilter} },
                                {message: { like: keywordFilter} }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };
} else {
  whereFilter = {status: {"neq": -1}, createdBy: currentUserId};
}



Alerts.find({where: whereFilter, include: [{relation: 'alertTypes'}], order: ["status ASC", "createdAt DESC"]}, function (err, alerts) {

});
```

Comment: If you are using mongo 3.2 or greater you can use $lookup which works similar to SQL's left outer join. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup

Comment: Thanks. lookup is working. Is there any way to get from the loopback mongo query instead of these aggregate function?

Comment: Even with Mongoose you need to use aggregate to perform lookup, if that's what you mean.